# Hoover windtunnel bagless vacuum stopped spinning only when it is not on upright position

Tags: central-vacuum

when I push the foot lever to lower the handle, the brushes stop spinning on any carpet level setting. Once the vacuum is locked into an upright position, they spin perfectly. I checked the belt and it looks fine. Should I change the belt?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the belt has stretched or worn to the point that it is unable to spin the brush whenever the brush has to push against the carpet. Often in these conditions the belt may very well be able to spin the brush freely when the brush is not trying to push against anything.

Belts can also get old and hard with a glazed surface that prevents the motor shaft from getting a good grab against the belt. When you install a new belt you may note the difference in the rubbery grab of the new belt to the motor shaft.

So with that said - do try a new belt.

Comment: Also, assuming carpets or rugs, try setting the brush depth so it isn't digging into the carpet so heavily. Overdoing that puts more strain on the brush and its drive system, and makes slipping more likely. (Note that the reason you aren't having problems in the "latched upright" mode is that the vacuum actually lifts the brush a bit when you set it that way... in part to make adjusting brush depth easier.)

Comment: I had this problem with mine and new belts and cleaning it out fixed the issue. It worked a lot better overall after doing that. It was hard to find a place to buy the belt though.